# PHP: need this exact position of string with a wildcard

Tags: php, wordpress

First of all, thank you for reading this post and trying to help me. I am pretty new to php and i have some struggle.

I have created a filter in wordpress which should check two conditions. the filter is working fine however i have ran it some problems.

this is my code

```
     function em_validate($result, $EM_Event){

        if ($_REQUEST['em_tickets'] > 1 && $_REQUEST['booking_comment'] == ''){
        $EM_Event->add_error('Something');  
        $result = false; 
     }
     return $result;
    }

add_filter('em_booking_validate','em_validate', 1, 2);
```

This filter works fine, however the content of `$_REQUEST['em_tickets'])`
is something like

```
<p><strong>23</strong></p><ul><li>5</li></ul><p></p>
```

i need to get the value in `<li> </li>` inorder to get my script work properly.

```
if ($_REQUEST['em_tickets'] > 1 && $_REQUEST['booking_comment'] == ''){
```

thank you for reading this post and coming with suggestions

suggestion two: which is also not working properly

```
function em_validate($result, $EM_Event){
$start = "<li>";
$end = "</li>";
    if (substr($_REQUEST['em_tickets'], $start, $end) > 1 && $_REQUEST['booking_comment'] == ''){
  $EM_Event->add_error($_REQUEST['em_tickets']); //('Something');


    $result = false;

 }
 return $result;
}
add_filter('em_booking_validate','em_validate', 1, 2);
```

Comment: Regexps or some xml-manipulation.

Comment: anyone who can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with DOM on JavaScript, you will find this solution pretty simple, use DOMDocument

```
<?php
    $html = "<p><strong>23</strong></p><ul><li>5</li><li>25</li></ul><p></p>";
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $liElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');

    foreach($liElements as $li) {
        var_dump($li->textContent);
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry not for elaborating my question properly. i need something like reading this 25th string of $_REQUEST['em_tickets']) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions for something like html or xml. Instead, use `DOMDocument` because that's designed to work with those non-regular structures.

```
$result = null;
$em_tickets = $_REQUEST['em_tickets']

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($em_tickets);
$lis = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');
if ($lis->length > 0) {
    $li = $lis[0];
    $result = $li->textContent;
}
```

Error checking could probably be improved.

Comment: This code sets `$result` to the contents of the first `li` element. It's up to you to do something with that content.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
$em_tickets = "<p><strong>23</strong></p><ul><li>5</li></ul><p></p>";

$start = "<li>";
$end = "</li>";

$id = substr($em_tickets, $start, $end);
```

Output :

```
 5
```

Note:

Using offset is not equivalent to passing substr($subject, $offset) to preg_match() in place of the subject string, because pattern can contain assertions such as ^, $ or (?<=x). Compare:

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: so you mean something like this    function em_validate($result, $EM_Event){
$em_tickets123 = $_REQUEST['em_tickets'];
$start = "<li>";
$end = "</li>";
$ssid = substr($em_tickets, $start, $end);
    if ($ssid  > 1 && $_REQUEST['booking_comment'] == ''){
  $EM_Event->add_error($_REQUEST['em_tickets']); //('Something');
  
  
    $result = false;
 
 }
 return $result;
}
add_filter('em_booking_validate','em_validate', 1, 2);

Comment: No, `substr()` doesn't work like that. It required `long`s for the second and third parameters and does not work when `string`s are given.

Comment: Its works.. substr — Return part of a string :  string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )  Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php ... Demo : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp